# Apache SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: apache

I have an error when running an https request:

> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>   (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

I run it on a Windows 7 box with Apache 2.x, and my Apache setting vhost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName repocenter.com  
    ServerAlias www.repocenter.com  
    ServerAdmin root@repocenter.com  
    <Proxy *>  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Proxy>  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.210.1:9991/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.210.1:9991/  
    SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1  
    CustomLog logs/repocenter.com-access.log common  
    ErrorLog logs/repocenter.com-error.log  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost _default_:443>   
    ServerName repocenter.com:443  
    ServerAlias www.repocenter.com:443   
    ServerAdmin root@repocenter.com       
    <Proxy *>  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Proxy>  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.210.1:9991/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.210.1:9991/  
    SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1     
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it a syntax error, and how would I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

That usually means that you are sending a HTTPS request to a HTTP service. The message is from the browser complaining that it was unable to to complete the SSL handshake that it was expecting. The syntax is correct, or the HTTPD would not have completed restarting the httpd service.

Comment: Wow, this was annoying me a lot and all I had to do was change the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

1. The file `/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` was configured with the correct SSL information but isn't being loaded because httpd.conf isn't loading it.

   To fix this error, uncomment the following line (remove the #). Then restart Apache.

   ```
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
   ```
2. Apache isn't set to listen on port 443 for secure traffic. To fix this, add the following line before the `<VirtualHost>` block is loaded:

   ```
   Listen 443
   ```

   If you're using IPv6 you'll need to include the IP address as well as the port:

   ```
   Listen 192.168.0.1:443
   ```
3. If you're running HTTPS on a non-standard port you'll need to tell Apache to listen for an SSL connection on that port:

   ```
   Listen 192.168.0.1:8443 https
   ```
4. If you see the above inside of an `<If DefineSSL>` block, you need to make sure you are defining SSL when you start Apache. Normally SSL should be defined on its own, but if it isn't being defined you can try the following commands for earlier versions of Apache 2:

   ```
   path/to/httpd -D SSL -k start
   path/to/apachectl startssl
   path/to/httpd startssl
   ```
5. If you're running Apache under Windows make sure the host file on the Windows server is set up correctly. It should be in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. Some people fix this error by changing `VirtualHost your.domain.com:443` to `VirtualHost _default_:443`, etc.
6. Make sure in the `<VirtualHost>` block Apache is configured to use SSL with the `SSLEngine` directive as follows:

   ```
   <VirtualHost your.domain.com:443>
   SSLEngine On
   [rest of VirtualHost]
   </VirtualHost>
   ```